# Adding image to seed database in rails 5.2 active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Just trying to add an image to my seed file. Having a little issue when trying to add using the new active storage in Rails 5.2

Can anyone spot what's happening. Here is the code followed by error in db. Thanks.

```
25.times do
temp = Post.create([{
    title: Faker::Book.unique.title,
    content: Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(rand(100..200)).join('\n'),
    category_id: rand(1..5),
    user_id: 1,
    status: 1,
    recommended: [true, false].sample,
    excerpt: Faker::Lorem.paragraph(10) 
        }])
  puts Post.first.featured_image
  temp.first.featured_image.attach(io: File.open('/Users/bradley/'), filename: 'Dart.png', content_type: 'image/png')
```

end

Error:

```
#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007fb672434448>
rake aborted!
Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ io_fread - /Users/bradley/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a directory not a file in this code:

```
File.open('/Users/bradley/')
```

If your image path is: `/Users/bradley/Dart.png`. Then you need to change your code:

```
File.open('/Users/bradley/Dart.png')
```

However I would not recommend to use absolute paths in your project even if it was only for seeds. You can add the image to your rails project and use relative path to your project.

Comment: Perfect Tarek. Thanks a million for the explanation. Simple stuff. Thought I was naming the path then the file separately. Cheers dude. Good advice on the absolute path as well. Thanks.

Comment: should the file directory for the assets folder not be as simple as....

temp.first.featured_image.attach(io: File.open('/assets/images/Dart.png'), filename: 'Dart.png', content_type: 'image/png')

or 

temp.first.featured_image.attach(io: File.open('Dart.png'), filename: 'Dart.png', content_type: 'image/png')

Comment: You are using `/assets/images/Dart.png` which is still absolute path because you start with `/`. It should be `assets/images/Dart.png` or `./assets/images/Dart.png`.

However as a nice practice I'd recommend to use:

`Rails.root.join('assets/images/Dart.png')`

to be something like:

`temp.first.featured_image.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('assets/images/Dart.png')), filename: 'Dart.png', content_type: 'image/png')`